# trying to insert super table field values using graphql in craft cms

Tags: craft3, matrix, plugin-supertable, graphql

cant able to store values from super table field,need a correct format to do

Graphql

```
mutation saveEntry($superTable: [demoSuperTable_SuperTableBlockContainerInput] = {demoSuperTable_0: {id: "", rowField1: ""}}, $stSortOrder: [QueryArgument]) {
  save_testing_testing_Entry(
    demoSuperTable: {blocks: $superTable, sortOrder: $stSortOrder}
  ) {
    demoSuperTable {
      ... on demoSuperTable_BlockType {
        id
        rowField1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Querying Variable

```
{
  "superTable": [
    {
      "demoSuperTable_0": {
        "id": 36,
        "rowField1": "demo"
      }
    }
  ],
  "stSortOrder": "new1"
}
```

output:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Demo Super Table should contain at least 1 block.",
      "extensions": {[![enter image description here][1]][1]
        "category": "user"
      },...
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since super table doesn't have block name like matrix and neo field. it required to points using block id. need modification in plugin code and try.
refer following link for reference and its working
https://github.com/verbb/super-table/issues/449